# iOS: Blur with custom shape

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `GameViewController` with some different subviews representing game object, such as scores, players, history, etc...

The user can drag around custom shapes on the GameBoard (`CAShapeLayer`).

I want to add a blur to the custom shapes. However, to first blur the background with all the game elements and then mask the image to the custom shape is horrible slow. 
Is this possible to do with good performance, and how would you do it in that case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `GPUImage` library if you are concerned about performance.       `https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage`

This tutorial will guide you completely about how to use the blur functionality you need:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage